# What's a saner way of converting a char to a char[]?

Tags: c#

I have something similar to the code below. **InheritedThing** is a **char[]?** property in the base class.

✅This works:

```
            string mystring = "hello";
            char[] ca = { mystring[0] };
            InheritedThing = ca;
```

❌This shortcut does not:

```
            string mystring = "hello";
            InheritedThing = { mystring[0] };
```

It gives me the red squigglies under the curly braces. Why?

Is it because the IDE can't determine what kind of array I'm passing? If so, how do I typecast the anonymous array so that it knows it is a char[]?

Comment: Welcome King Charles. Regarding the 2nd one, you can try `InheritedThing = new[]{ mystring[0] };`. Otherwise it looks like Llama's answer would produce your desired result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are your options for making a new char array initialized to a value (without relying on a method that returns a char array):

```
//when you're declaring the variable too
char[] c = new char[] { 'x' };
char[] c = new[] { 'x' };
char[] c = { 'x' };

var c = new char[] { 'x' };
var c = new[] { 'x' };

//when assigning to an existing variable, new keyword I required
Thing = new char[] { 'x' };
Thing = new[] { 'x' };
```

I tend to use the `new[] { ... }` shortcut everywhere, because it works consistently regardless the context (unless the c# version is too old to permit it). Might also be worth noting that in cases where the compiler is figuring out the type for the array, it just uses the first element so you're allowed to put different types as long as they're implicitly convertible to the type of the first

```
var nums = new[] { 1m, 1, 'a' };
```

This ends up as a `decimal[]` because an int and a char can be implicitly converted to it (char becoming the numeric index of its position in the character table, so 'a' is 97)

Comment: Thank you! It was the new[] I was missing that caused the squigglies. Really appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Addressing a saner way to do it: you can use the `string`'s [`.ToCharArray`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.tochararray?view=net-6.0#system-string-tochararray(system-int32-system-int32)) method, which takes the start index and desired length:

```cs
InheritedThing = mystring.ToCharArray(0, 1);
```

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/HGEVG42613)

Answer (score 2):

You can retain the brackets syntax by adding `new []` right before the brackets:

```
char[] InheritedThing;
var mystring = "hello";
InheritedThing = new[] { mystring[0] };
```

Comment: Thank you! It was the new[] I was missing that caused the squigglies. Really appreciated!

Comment: You welcome !!!